# Change voice channel server region discord js

Tags: discord.js

I need to change a voice channel region to `Russia` using `discord JS`. I can't find anything anywhere. Is it possible to do this using bot? I am creating auto voice channels but no one is able to talk in these voice channels because of the region. Any help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, we work on the policy that the user must show an attempt before getting assistance. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Please refer to [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if you are using stable version custom region for voice channel is not release yet . Try to using `master` for new cool stuff . In `master` to set region for voice channel you need to using `.setRTCRegion` for more details [docs here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=setRTCRegion)

To using master branch of discord.js

```
npm i discordjs/discord.js
```